# How to add a new file property by using alternative data streams

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

When i research a malware, it seems that the malware adds a new shortcut property to the PE files by using Alternative Data Streams. It can't be debugged and i can only collect some information from ProcessMonitor. The following is the related APIs the malware calls:

```
CreateFile("C:\Test.exe:!",...)

ZwFsControlFile(.. FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT ..)
```

Is there any body knows how to add a user defined property by Alternative Data Streams?
Thanks.

Comment: NtCreateFile is the api you want to look for, the links in the answer by mox are a bit stale, For anyone like me having the same question here also a bit late, try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141949/337598

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of information on the web that answer your question..

[Practical Guide to Alternative Data Streams in NTFS](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds)

[Alternate Data Streams: Out of the Shadows and into the Light](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/honors/alternate-data-streams-shadows-light_1503)

Comment: I have read a lot of information about ADS. But all of them are about how to write, read, and delete Alternative Data Streams, and there is little information about user defined attributes by ADS. I still don't know how to add the user defined properties to the file by ADS. Could you please help me on it? Thanks.

Comment: as described in the urls, an ADS is just one (named) stream among the main (unnamed) stream of an NTFS file. "User defined properties" would be just an additional ADS.